# How to get a Text type instead of String type in liferay service

Tags: hibernate, liferay, liferay-6, database-migration

Say you have this kind of entity in your service.xml

```
<entity name="Answer" local-service="true" remote-service="true">
    <!-- PK fields -->
    <column name="answer_id" type="long" primary="true" />
    <!-- Other fields -->
    <column name="user_id" type="long" />
    <column name="answer" type="String" />
    <column name="date_answered" type="Date" />
</entity>
```

My understanding, looking at posts like [this](https://www.dnebinger.com/wiki/-/wiki/Portal+Development/Creating+the+Liferay+Service) and [this](http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/applying-convert-null-attribute-in-service-builder-to-persist-null-and-not-null-into-data-types-in-databases), is that using the Liferay 6 Service Builder, you can only specify a type String but not Text. If you want to use a Text type, you have to modify the generated SQL script by hand. It seems that you can also edit the portlet-model-hints.xml file, like so

```
<field name="answer" type="String">
    <hint name="max-length">5000</hint>
</field>
```

in which case the field type will be set to "TEXT" in the generated SQL file.

But what if you need to update the "answer" field from a string to a text field, the tables having already be generated following the first schema ?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

Idealy it should automatically alter the database table when you make some changes to the service.xml.

1) Try un-deploying the portlet
2) Clearing the work and temp folder
3) Restart the server
4) and then re-deploy the portlet

Note: Updating the portlet-model-hints.xml, is the right way to go rather than updating the sql file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I already did all this (I'm getting used to this process !) but for some reason it doesn't update the database. Maybe it's because it already contains data ? It's strange, as I thought that having the build number incremented in the service.properties file (that is after you run ant build-service) would trigger a schema update... but no.
Thanks anyway !

Comment: Even if it contains data it does trigger an update of the table, wonder why it is not happening with you. can you try adding another column to the service.xml and see if it works? or changing the name of your column to see if it works? So that you can be sure its not updating at all or its just not changing the capacity of the column which has data.

Comment: Thanks Prakash. It didn't update the DB, although both the service.properties and tables.sql files were updated.

Answer (score 0):

In that case delete all entries from tables.sql and after updating the field rebuild your service.

Comment: well the tables.sql get updated, but when I deploy the portlet, the DB schema does not get changed. Do I need to drop the tables, or is there a more "graceful" way ?

Comment: In that case first try with restart your server, and if this will not work for you then drop the tables.

Comment: It seems that just restarting the server doesn't work. I find it quite aggressive to just drop tables... Thanks anyway